# I want id of image on click of delete button

Tags: reactjs

**i want id of the particular image at Onclick in reactjs. we have an array with all the data about images  i.e. images[ ]. How to pass the id of that particular image to delete it to deleteimage function. any suggestion or advice will be welcomed **

```
class Image extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { images: [] };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    let result = apiGateway.getImages();
    if (result != null) {
      result.then((value) => {
        this.setState({ images: value.data.data });
      });
    }
  }

   deleteImage=()=>{

    let result = apiGateway.removeImage(??);
  }



renderImage(value,index){
  let str = value.imagePath.split('/').pop();
  let string = str.slice(0,-5);
  return(
    <div key={index}>
     <p>Title: {value.title}</p>
     <p>Description: {value.description}</p>
    <button onClick={this.deleteImage}>DELETE</button>
    <button>UPDATE</button>
    <img className='image' src= {'http://localhost:3000/'+ string } width='100' height='100' alt='nature'/>
    <br/><br/>
    </div>
    );
}


  render() {

    return(  
                 <div>
                      <div>{
                        this.state.images.map((image,index)=>{

                          return this.renderImage(image,index);
                        })
                      }
                      </div>
                </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Image;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try send `value` to `deleteImage(value)` function:

`<button onClick={this.deleteImage.bind(this, value)}>DELETE</button>`

OR

`<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteImage(value, e)}>DELETE</button>`

Please view more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)